# Permutations of $3$ elements which sum to $100$

Tags: permutations

I need to find the number of permutations of $3$ elements which add up to $100$. For each element, $0 \leq x \leq 100$. So we could have $0,0,100$; $1,0,99$; $0,1,99$ etc. Order is important - I need to count $1,0,99$ as well as $0,1,99$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you heard of [stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and [bars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTCScjoPymA)?

Comment: I am sorry for the downvotes ZebE. Sounds like a perfectly well-asked question to me. Please accept my upvote as an apology for the other harsh people on this site.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: You should specify that the elements in question are nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This problem is the same as distributing 100 balls into 3 distinct boxes i.e.

$$x+y+z=100$$

Each ball (=the number $1$) is identical and the boxes ($x,y,z,$) are distinct

Answer (score 0):

Using another formulation, you need to solve $x+y+z=100$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$.

A hint: count all $(x,y) \in [0,100]$ such that $x+y\leq100$. This is rather easy.

Then, introduce $z$ in the play.